# using spawn to restart NODE server if error happened

Tags: node.js

I'm trying this code to restart the node server if it stopped accidentally,  in this example "x" is not defined, so should give an error and re-start, but actually the server completely exit.

```
var http = require('http');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
   console.log(x);
});

server.listen(8125, 'localhost', function(err) {
    if(err) spawn('node',['./server.js']);
});

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8125/');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you can't catch the error in server.listen, you should add an event handler to your main process,  so when an exception or an error occurred the event handler will manage this exception, the code below is an example of handling an error in node.js script.

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
   console.log(x);
});

server.listen(8125, 'localhost');

process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
    // Add some code here to process the excpetion
    console.log('I m here');
});

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8125/');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [forever.js](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) which will restart your process should it crash. Just make sure there aren't any bugs that will keep crashing each instance (basically, make sure your app works so forever doesn't keep trying to restart a broken app).